# Unable to accept UAA agreement on Jenkins build for Grails

Tags: grails, licensing, jenkins, cloudbees

My Grails jobs fails on Jenkins provided by Cloudbees because they require to accept UAA agreement.

Is there a way to accept agreements?

Comment: Can you give more details on why it fails?

Comment: what's your cloudbees account ? I'd like to see the actual log and grails version

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Grails plugin can be configured to run in non-interactive mode, that should fix this issue